# How to define foreign key, index constraints in my migration script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I define foreign key, index constraints in my db migration script for my Rails app in a `2.3.x` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't support adding foreign keys in a database-agnostic way, so you'll need to do this with DB-specific code. Here's an example for MySQL:

```
class AddForeignKeyToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute 'alter table users add constraint user_role foreign key user_role_idx (role_id) references roles (id) on delete set null on update cascade'
  end

  def self.down
    execute 'alter table users drop foreign key user_role'    
  end
end
```

For indexes, you can use `add_index` - like so:

```
add_index(:users, :name)
```

**Edit:** Updated answer to clarify that indexes and foreign keys are treated differently.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a database agnostic fashion and also a migration to Rails3 in the near future.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but my experience with Rails 3 is fairly limited so far. I updated the answer since it was misleading regarding the way foreign keys and indexes are treated.

Comment: I am looking for a solution which will be compliant for Rails 2.3.x.