# referencing a specified column in a table from another table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two migrations as below:

```
CreateGroups
  t.string :name
  t.string :groupkey

CreateEvents
  t.string :name
  t.string :groupkeyname
  t.integer :group_id
```

and their corresponding models:

```
group
  has_many :events

event
  belongs_to :group
```

from what I understand is that the t.integer :group_id column in the CreateEvents migration references the default id column in the CreateGroups migration. However, I want :groupkeyname from CreateEvents to reference  :groupkey  in CreateGroups such that when I add an event with groupkeyname = groupkey it automatically references the group in question. How do i do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the custom foreign key in your model.
Check out this link : http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/32-custom-foreign-keys-in-ruby-on-rails
or if you know the sql command for the foreign key you can write that command in migration file. 
Check this link: [How to define foreign key, index constraints in my migration script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526600/how-to-define-foreign-key-index-constraints-in-my-migration-script)

Comment: thanks for your answer but the first link: I have no idea what that guy is doing... there is very little explanation! the second link is too cumbersome especially when dealing with rollbacks..plus i'm using 3.0.11 there I'm sure I can use foreign_key but don't understand it how it works!! If somebody could explain it with a nice little example!

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegates for this. Check this blog for a more thorough explanation: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/